# Buffering/Syncing remote (webRTC) mediaStreams

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, webrtc

I am currently building a webRTC application that streams audio (the classic server, client, one to many model). Communication and signaling is done through sockets.

The problem I have found is that there is a lot of variability when streaming to smart devices (mainly due to varying processing power), even on a local network.

Hence, I am trying to add functionality that syncs the stream between devices. At a high level I was thinking of potentially, buffering the incoming stream, once all devices are connected the last peer to connect will share something that indicates where that specific peer's buffer starts and all peers will play the buffer from that position.

Does this sound possible? Is there a better way to sync up remote streams? If I was to go along this path, how would I go about buffering a remote MediaStream object (or data from a BlobURL) potentially into some form of array which can be used to identify a common starting location between the streams?

Would I potentially use the Javascript AudioContext api?

I have also looked at NTP protocols and other syncing mechanism but I couldn't find how to apply them to in the context of a webRTC application.

Any help, pointers, or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: rtc is peer to peer, not peer to peers. you need a server that can act as an rtc peer and then transcode that stream to something more than one device can connect to, like hls.

Comment: Yes, I am using a node js server to maintain all the connections and then I relay the same getMedia stream to all the connected peers which successfully creates a one to many stream.